# Use android package manager in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

Trying to check if a particular application is installed in the android phone or not.

In android studio, I used Package manager to get the installation status of the application. But I need to use Xamarin.Forms for development.

Comment: I have read online that Dependency injection can be used for such purposes, but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,you could use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to achive this:

first,define a **Interface** :

```
public interface IsInstallApplication
 {
     bool IsInstall(string packageName);
 }
```

then in **Droid.project** create a class which implement the interface :

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AndroidIsInstallApplication))]// do not miss the line
namespace App18.Droid
{
   class AndroidIsInstallApplication : IsInstallApplication
     {
        public bool IsInstall(string packageName)
         {
            ... //here you could use Package manager to get the installation status of the application like in native android
            return true;
         }
     }
}
```

finally you could call it in you page like :

```
DependencyService.Get<IsInstallApplication>().IsInstall(packageName);
```

Comment: you could define a static variable in MainActivity，for example ：public static MainActivity Instance；then in the OnCreate method ：Instance = this； you could use MainActivity.Instance.PackageManager，or you could use a CurrentActivity Nuget to get current activity，then call currentActivity.PackageManager

Comment: I will try that as well. For now I used Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager to get the package manager in the non activity class.