# XAMARIN Android App, how do I get a list of installed apps as a service in MVVM?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

1. I want to load a list of installed applications on an Android phone.
2. I am trying to build a Xamarin Forms application leveraging the MVVM framework.
3. I am using Visual Studio 2019 Pro and Xamarin Forms

I keep finding articles talking about `Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.GetInstalledApplications` however I have not been able to figure out how to get get a reference to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566727/use-android-package-manager-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: I read that question before but there are two things still not explained in that question.

1. What/Where do I do that and how?  It gives an answer but I need more clarity.  It also does not seem to be done within the Xamarin Project.

2. That question/answer you referenced is for when you _know_ the name of the application you are looking for.

Comment: You're right that it doesn't go into the detail I thought it did at first glance.  However, the general approach of using DependencyService to access an Android specific implementation from Forms is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement this using dependency service. I will give in detail so others who are new to Xamarin also might understand.

First we will create our model. You can name this as `InApp.cs` in Shared directory.

```
public class InApp
{
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public string PackageName { get; set; }

    public InApp(string appName, string packageName)
    {
        AppName = appName;
        PackageName = packageName;
    }
}
```

Now we can create our dependency service in `Android` Folder. Name this as `AndroidService.cs`.

```
public class AndroidService : IAndroidService
{
    public List<InApp> GetIntalledApps()
    {
        List<InApp> inApps = new List<InApp>();
        IList<ApplicationInfo> apps = Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.GetInstalledApplications(PackageInfoFlags.MatchAll);
        for (int i = 0; i < apps.Count; i++)
        {
            inApps.Add(new InApp(apps[i].LoadLabel(Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager), apps[i].PackageName));
        }
        return inApps;
    }
}
```

The above code will get the installed apps, then creates a `List` of the model which we've created above and returns it.

At run time, Xamarin should know where to look for the dependency service, so for that we should add this above the name space of `AndroidService` class we've created above.

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(AndroidService))]
```

`IAndroidService` is the interface which will access the `Android` folder `AndroidService` class at runtime. We will create this class in Shared directory. We can name this as `IAndroidService.cs`.

```
public interface IAndroidService
{
    List<InApp> GetIntalledApps();
}
```

Now we have completed our dependency service implementation. Next part is to create a `ListView` and add the returned installed apps list from our Android service.

Since we are doing this in `MVVM`, we will create a view model now.

Create `InstalledAppViewModel.cs` in Shared directory.

```
public class InstalledAppViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<InApp> installedApps;
    public ObservableCollection<InApp> InstalledApps
    {
        get { return installedApps; }
        set
        {

            installedApps = value;
        }
    }

    public InstalledAppViewModel()
    {
        List<InApp> listOfInstalledApps = DependencyService.Get<IAndroidService>().GetIntalledApps();
        InstalledApps = new ObservableCollection<InApp>(listOfInstalledApps);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Above, we have done the dependency injection and added the returned values from the `GetInstalledApps` method to our `Observable` list.

Now in your `MainPage.Xaml.Cs` bind the view model.

```
BindingContext = new InstalledAppViewModel();
```

Add the list view in your `MainPage.Xaml`.

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding InstalledApps}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Label Text="{Binding AppName}" FontSize="Medium" />
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

In `ItemSource` of the list view attribute, you are binding the `Observable` list which we have created in the View Model class.